Continuously process data stream from external program in Matlab
So, I have written a C program that starts an external sensor module and then gets a stream of measurements from the sensor until the process is interrupted. Currently it just writes the measurements to stdout, but I could easily modify it to write them to a file.
Now, what I would like to do is to continuously process the stream of measurements within Matlab. How I picture it in my head is something like the following. A class SensorInterface with a function StartMeasuring which runs the external C program, perhaps in the background. Then maybe a callback function which activates when a new measurement arrives, if that is possible. Whether I should write the measurements to a file inbetween, or just read the stdout from the program, I am not sure.
What is a good way to do this? I've tried searching for similar questions, but with little success. The documentation (say, here and here) does not seem discuss this sort of continuous streaming scenario.
I'm on Linux, if that makes any difference.

Here's a pretty simple sketch of one way to approach this:

Allocate names for a couple of files - a "kill file" which will tell your executable to stop, and an output file to which it should write data. Use tempname for this.
Launch your executable using system('myExecutable killFile outputFile &') - this will start "myExecutable" running in the background
Modify "myExecutable" so that it periodically checks for the existence of "killFile" - and quits if it does exist ; also, write results to outputFile
Use a MATLAB timer to read data from "outputFile" every so often
Get your MATLAB code to create "killFile" to stop "myExecutable" from running.

You could imagine plenty of refinements to this depending on your specific requirements. But that's where I'd start.

If you want to go to a more sophisticated approach, you could consider something more like this

Since you wrote the C code, you could wrap it up as a MEX file.
Inside your MEX file, allocate a static data structure to use as a conduit for measurements. Also allocate a static std::atomic<bool> to use as a "stop flag".
Launch a thread to take measurements and push them into your static data structure (in a thread-safe manner).
Use a timer to pull data from your MEX file's data structure when available.

That approach needs more care to make sure everything is thread-safe, and that you don't accidentally leak threads, data, etc.
Another refinement you could make if you have Parallel Computing Toolbox available - instead of using a timer, you could use a parallel.pool.DataQueue to push the data from the worker, and use afterEach on the client to respond to the new data.

I thought about doing something like this. Is there not risk for race conditions? I have also considered using a named pipe. Do you see any particular issues with such an approach?

The main risk is probably reading partially-written data, which I suppose is a kind of race condition. I'll update my comment with another approach you could consider.

I have also considered the alternative of converting my C program into a shared library (this would not be much work), and then using Matlab's loadlibrary, calllib, etc. to use it. Does that seem like a reasonable way to go? I am a little worried about the performance of calllib, since I might need to use it for (somewhat fast) polling. Also, it is a bit impractical that calllib doesn't allow me to get the stdout from the library calls.

I'm not very familiar with callib to be honest, but it probably lets you do something similar to the MEX approach.
